# Force of interest piecewise function to find nominal yearly interest

Tags: finance

I have been given a question that asks to calculate the nominal yearly interest rate from the force of interest of the following piecewise function:

[image: Piecewise function]

I initially approached this question by doing the following.

[image: Derived method]

From this point onwards i solve for the force of interest by breaking up the piecewise function into three seperate definite integrals and adding them together and then proceed to to solve for i in the derived equation.

When doing the relevant calculations from using this approach i have been getting an incorrect answer. Is this the correct approach or have i made a mistake in my calculations

Comment: I am new to stack exchange and I don't understand why the piecewise function photo won't appear.

Comment: Your approach is correct as you describe it, but I don't see your integrals. If anything is wrong, it must be there. Also, I fixed your first image.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the feedback. If you don't mind could you write out what the integrals would be, maybe I'm doing something wrong with the upper and lower boundaries.